# Eclipse giving error when compiler does not

Tags: eclipse, stanford-nlp

I've come up against an odd issue in Eclipse while using the Stanford CoreNLP API. I've written a custom implementation of the  [Annotator interface](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotator.html), which amongst other things specifies two methods with the type signature `Set<Class<? extends CoreAnnotation>>`.

I've implemented those methods, but Eclipse is showing an error telling me that the type signature is incorrect. Specifically, it reports, `The return type is incompatible with Annotator.requires()`. The recommended fix suggests changing the return type to exactly the same type I already have written, but still leaves the error:

[image: Screenshot showing Eclipse error on type signature]

As you can see, the supposed `incorrect' type is exactly the same as the type given in the interface.

The project compiles correctly using `mvn compile`, so this isn't an actual compiler problem. Has anyone seen this before, and can you advise as to how to make those errors go away?

**Edit:** added screenshot showing the error

**Edit2**: added details of the error message in Eclipse

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. Is this the only error displayed in the project? (What you see is an error found by the Eclipse Java compiler. In contrast, in Maven `javac` is used by default. Which Eclipse version and which JDK version in Maven do you use?)

Comment: Exact error message added. This is indeed the only error in the project. Currently using Eclipse 4.7.3a, and Maven is set to use JDK version 1.8.

Comment: I would check the eclipse preferences to see if the target folder are the same as Maven (/bin vs /target). Check also your imports to be sure they are the same between Eclipse and Maven (Maven is more strict than eclipse with the classpath). You could also try to reimport the project in eclipse. In the past I got some success doing that.

Comment: If you uncomment the method and type `requires`+Ctrl+Space what code snippet did the content assist propose to overwrite `requires()`?